# How to get item specification from ebay call

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to create url request to ebay to get the item specification
like screen size, cpu, and so on.
tried to look on ebay document but didn't find how to do that,

Hope you can help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your code i can only suggest you this which will all active items with all details:

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$eBay->auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ActiveList>
<Sort>Title</Sort>
<IncludeNotes>FALSE</IncludeNotes>
<Pagination><EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>$pageNo</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
</ActiveList>
<HideVariations>FALSE</HideVariations>
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Version>$eBay->api_version</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetMyeBaySellingRequest>​
EOD;

$feed = trim($feed);
        $site_id = 3;//3 For UK
        $headers = array
            (
            'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: ' . $this->api_version,
            'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $this->dev_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $this->app_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $this->cert_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ' . $call_name,
            'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: ' . $site_id,
        );

        // Send request to eBay and load response in $response
        $connection = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_endpoint);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $feed);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($connection);
        curl_close($connection);
```

Comment: My code is in java, but I was looking for url api somthing like this http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=iphone%205s

Comment: Try this library https://www.temboo.com/

Comment: sorry but what did you send isnt related to this issue!

Answer (score 0):

[`GetItem`](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetItem.html#Response.Item.ItemSpecifics) is what you're looking for, with `IncludeItemSpecifics` set to `true`.

Or, a lighter API call using [`GetSingleItem`](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) from the Shopping API, with `IncludeSelector` set to `ItemSpecifics`.